# How can I count the number of occurences of a scalar in a vector, in APL

Tags: apl

For example I have a vector `'H2DH2DH'`, is there a way to count the number of `'H'` scalars that appear?

Comment: @ShawnC. Why the removal of tags?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean you have the character vector `'H2DH2DH'` and want to count how many scalar `'H'` characters are in there.

`'H'='H2DH2DH` will give you a Boolean vector indicating where the desired characters are. `+/'H'='H2DH2DH'` will sum that, and give you the count.

[Play with it on TryAPL!](http://tryapl.org/?a=+/%27H%27%3D%27H2DH2DH%27&run)

You can also define a generalised function which takes a scalar as left argument and a vector as right argument and counts the number of occurrences of the scalar in the vector.

Some APL systems (e.g. Dyalog, GNU, and ngn) will let you write `CountIn←{+/⍺=⍵}` where `⍺` stands for the left argument, and `⍵` for the right argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zm/NK/EM@9R24Rqbf1HvbtsH/Vurf3/X91DXQEqpaDuYeQCQuoA) The remaining systems (e.g. APLX, APL+WIN, and APL2) will have you type:

```
∇ count←char CountIn text
  count←+/char=text
∇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FHu0JyfmleyaO2CckZiUUKziCOZ55CSWpFCZcCXE5bHyRrCxYF6vn/X91DHa5W3cPIBYTUAQ)

Comment: @RichardAdams: can you pls. accept the answer, so that the question is no longer shown as "open" (just tick the check-mark next to the reply).

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you prefer, to count the occurrences using inner product:

`'H'+.='H2DH2DH'`

(Years ago, on other implementations, `+/'H'='H2DH2DH'` may have been slightly faster, perhaps this is still true)